# What is $asset_id value in configuration.php file for?

Tags: joomla-3.x, global-configuration

I've noticed this a value at the end of my **configuration.php** file in Joomla 3.3.6:

```
public $asset_id = '1';
```

What is that for? Maybe a default fallback?

Answer (score 1):

This is not a default variable for Joomla 3.x's ([or any other version](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/joomla-3/news/config-changes)) *configuration.php* file. I've done a check to see if this variable is being used anywhere else in Joomla's core. It is, however it's not being called from the *configuration.php*.

I'm not sure how it got there but the *configuration.php* should never get changed by any other extensions. The only time it changes or when it should change is when:

1. There's a Joomla update
2. You manually make changes (i.e if you move your site to a different host)
3. You make changes in the Joomla Global Configuration

I would suggest taking a backup of this file and removing `public $asset_id = '1';` from the production file.